# Changing Windows taskbar auto-hide settings upon connecting an external monitor

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, multiple-monitors

I have a netbook running Windows 7. When using it normally, I like to have the taskbar auto-hide, but I frequently have an external monitor connected and much prefer the taskbar visible then.

Is there a way to get Windows to automatically change from auto-hide to normal and vice-versa depending on whether or not an external monitor is connected?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't automated, but the following answer provides a way to toggle auto-hide via AutoHotkey:

[How to toggle the auto-hide status of the Windows taskbar](https://superuser.com/questions/654170/how-to-toggle-the-auto-hide-status-of-the-windows-taskbar/)

I've found it very useful.